# Can I have this sentence corrected?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, sentence-choice

I'm not at all sure if the sentence is correct (I really hope that you can understand the message I'm trying to convey):

> "I had no idea that I'd react to her texting him the same way I have
>   when she has seen him"

I was hoping you could correct the sentence if it's wrong; and if not, suggest some other alternative sentences with the same meaning.

(I'm always looking to improve on my English, so I'd greatly appreciate it if you would point out any grammatical mistakes I've made in describing my question)

Comment: **When she has seen him** means she has seen him more than once. Is that what you want to say? Or did she see him only once? We can help if you explain that.

Comment: I meant it to be more than once; I'm mostly unsure about the second part of the sentence, where it says "the same way I have when she has seen him”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These work:

> I had no idea that I would react the same way to her texting him as I had
>   to her seeing him.
>
> I had no idea that I would react to her texting him the way I had
>   to her seeing him.

With two *I had*s and one *I'd* the sentence had become a little repetetive. So I changed your *I'd* to *I would*.

Alternatives? Well, you could rewrite it. For example:

> I was surprised to find myself reacting to her texting him exactly as
>   I had to her seeing him.

Please note that not one of these makes it clear whether or not she saw him more than once. They do all make it clear that she is no longer seeing him. If you would prefer NOT to make that clear, then you should change the final "had" to "did".